# Method that takes a 2D array as a parameter, in c

Tags: arrays, methods, parameters, 2d

I need to pass a 2D array into the method below:

`int pipeChild_1(int pipedes[], char *argsArray[][]);`

But the compiler gives that error:

`array has incomplete element type 'char *[]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that - 'c' only knows about pointers not about arrays.

If the size of the array is fixed (or at least the last dimension) you can pass that to the function, but a more common method is to pass a pointer to the array and the dimensions separately

eg [Passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c) or http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

Comment: Thanks, I've passed the dimensions and pointer separately. works fine.