# Why do I get that I'm passing an arguments from incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c)

I'm trying to use general swap function:

```
void swap(void **p, void **q){
    void *tmp;
    tmp=*p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=tmp;
}


int main(){
    int M=5;
    int N=6;
    char*w[M][N];

    swap(&w[1][2], &w[2][2]);

    return 0;
    }
```

### Let's assume that w is initialized already with values, I am wondering only about the way I should send the arguments

I'm trying to figure out how should I send the arguments to swap in this case.

Let's assume that N=M=2; so I have w looks like {{"stack", "overflow"},{"best", "site"}}

1. **swap(w[i][j],w[k][r])** is not the correct option since w[i][j] is reference to an actual string and swap gets **void, where only  w[i][j] is a pointer to only *char, so
2. **swap(&w[i][j], &w[k][r])** looks like the right options. since it's a pointer to char*, 
   but I get *passing arguments of swap from  incompatible pointer type*, How come?

Comment: You may have to cast the pointer type to void*? edit: I mean you have to cast void** to char*

Comment: What makes you think a ptr-to-ptr-to-char (from main) is compatible with a ptr-to-ptr-to-void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast `void**` to `char*`, or `char*` to `void**` depending on how you want the code to be written.

I don't think C supports any generic-ish way of having a function blind to the type of data it's working with.

The typical way of writing a swap function would be for each data type you expect to use it with so you would end up writing separate methods for swapping `int*`, `char*`, ect instead of using `void` pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert `char *` to `void *` (think if it as a special case), but you cannot convert `char **` to `void **` and do anything meaningful with the result.

For the same reason, you can convert `int` to `short`, but you cannot convert `int *` to `short *` and expect the compiler not to complain.

(It happens to work on common architectures, but nothing in the C standard guarantees that two different pointer types have the same representation, with a couple exceptions.)

```
void swap(char **p, char **q)
{
    char *tmp;
    tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `swap` function expects `void**` as arguments, but you pass `char**`s. That's what the compiler complains about. While all object-pointer types can be implicitly converted to `void*`, that is not true for `void**`, hence you have to cast the arguments,

```
swap((void**)&w[1][2], (void**)&w[2][2]);
```

Comment: I'd rather not sprinkle casts, but fix the swap function to take `char **` instead.

Comment: @Jens I had the impression it was intended to swap pointers to arbitrary type.