# how to pass 1D and 2D array arguments to a function in c

Tags: c, arrays, argument-passing

Suppose I have a function, `int function(int N, int c[N]){...}`, taking as parameters an integer and an array. Suppose now I have a double array `**c` of size 'N times 2' and suppose, I want to apply the function `function` to one column of the double arrow, `c[i][0]`, `i` varying from  to N-1. How am I supposed to use this function. Does it looks like something like `function(N,*c[0])` ?

Does anyone can help ?

Comment: When you write "double array" I think you mean "two dimensional array". A double array is something entirely different.

Comment: Yes sorry, I tought it was the right term. I meant two dimensional array

Comment: You should definitively read up on pointers and arrays in C. A two dimensional array and a pointer to pointer (your `**c`) completely different beasts and not compatible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c)

Comment: This is far too simple not to look up in a tutorial. And it also has been asked many times here. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array in C always decays to a pointer to its first element when passed into a function. This is good to know in some situations.

As an example, you could write

```
int list[10];
func (int *x) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         printf("%d", x[i]);
    }
 }
```

x[i] is really just syntactic sugar. In C, when you use bracket notation to access an element of an array, it gets converted to *(x + i), where x is the name of the array.

This works because of pointer arithmetic. If x is the name for an array of 10 integers, then the value of x in an expression is the address of the first integer of the array.

x + i will always point to the i-th element after x (C takes into account the size of the element type stored in the array, and increments the pointer accordingly).

Thus, when passing 2d arrays, the array decays to a pointer to its first element - which is an array.

A function signature taking a 2d array can be written as

```
func(int x[][columns] {
      ...
} 
// but could also be written as

func(int (*x)[columns]) {
    ...
}
```

which indicates that x is a pointer to an array of integers.

Sometimes you need to write a function to accept a 2 dimensional array where the width is not known until run time. In this case, you can pass a pointer to the [0][0] element and also pass the two dimensions, and then use pointer arithmetic to get the right element. For example,

```
print_2d_array (int *x, height, width) {
    int i, j;
       for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            printf("%d", x[i * width + j]);
         }
     }
}

int list[10][10];
print_2d_array (&list[0][0], 10, 10);
```

would work for a dynamically allocated 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

In c langauge, for single dimentional array you no need to mention the size of the array in the function arguments while passing an array to that function.

If it is a single dimentional array

```
...
int a[10];
func(10, a);
...
void func(int size, int x[]) //no need to mention like int x[10]
{
    //here x is not an array. Its equivalent to int *
    printf("%d", sizeof(x)); // this will print 4 or 8 not 40
}
```

If it is 2D array

```
...
int a[10][5];
func (10, a);
...

void (int rows, int x[][5])   //here int x[][] is invalid
{

}
```

Comment: You are correct that you don't have to mention the `N` in the first dimension, but it can be considered being good practice to show the intention of the code. And also for fixed sizes there is the notation `int x[static 10]` that requires that the array that is passed through the pointer has at least 10 elements.

Comment: OK, in fact whta I did is not working. if I take the example below abd suppose I call the function 'function' : void function(int rows, int x[][5]), suppose now I call this function later on my code, in I put function(rows,x), where x is the 2D arry you mentionned, it doesn't work....

Comment: @user1611830 : 2D array is working for me.  http://codepad.org/uNij4dkf   Check this link i have executed my program.