# Passing 2-D array to function in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c)

In C, 
 if I want a function to receive a 2-D array, can I use * notation for the function parameter

```
int (int my2dary[][10]);  //This is what I do not want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you pass a pointer to an array of int

```
int func(int (*my2dary)[10]);
```

and you call it

```
int a[5][10];
func(a);
```

Although, `func` doesn't know how many elements are in `my2dary`, so you must give a number too

```
int func(int n, int (*my2dary)[10]);
```

and call

```
int a[5][10];
func(5, a);
```

See [How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations) or [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you don’t know the size of the array at compile time, you may want:

```
int func(int *array, int size)
{
   int n,m;
   ... 
   array[m*size+n]; /* = array[m][n] if in the caller: int array[x][size]; */
}
```

Optionally (and very probably you need) you can pass a second size argument (x) to be able to test array boundary