# Error: cannot convert 'int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)n) + -1)) + 1)]' to 'int (*)[100]' for argument '1' to 'int determ(int (*)[100], int)'|

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I have that error but I'm sure I have the same data type and I didn't do anything wrong I suppose. It's for calculating the determinant of a matrix. Someone help. I really can't think of why I have this error :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double determinant(double matrix[100][100], int order)
{
    double det, temp[100][100]; int row, col;

    if (order == 1)
        return matrix[0][0];
    else if (order == 2)
        return ((matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]));
    else
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < order; r++)
        {
            row = 0;
            col = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < order; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < order; j++)
                {
                    if (j == r)
                        continue;

                    temp[row][col] = matrix[i][j];
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
            }
            det += (matrix[0][r] * pow(-1, r) * determinant(temp, order - 1));
        }
        return det;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the dimension: ";
    cin >> n;
    double elem[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter row " << i << ": ";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> elem[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << determinant(elem, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just answered a similar question. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26210551/434551

Comment: You will _never_ get that function to work. Consider rewriting the whole program without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

`double elem[n][n];` is illegal in C++. Arrays must have dimensions known at compiletime.

Your bizarre error message is a result of a compiler attempting to support `double elem[n][n]` as an extension, but not doing a very good job of it.

One way to fix this would be to change your code to be `double elem[100][100];` .

To fix it without wasting memory and sticking to Standard C++, you should use `std::vector` instead of a C-style array. It is simpler to code to use a vector of vectors, although for performance reasons you may want to use a 1-D vector.

Also, you would need to refactor `determinant` slightly as you don't really want to be allocating new memory each time you do another step of the recursion. The `determinant` function needs to know what dimension of memory is allocated, as well as what dimension you want to calculate the determinant on.

Answer (score 1):

your prototype is 
double determinant(double matrix[100][100], int order)

and you call it with 
determinant(elem, n);
when 
double elem[n][n]; that is a "dynamic" array size so not 100x100

it seam compiler assumes n is 1  at compile time so 
obviously double array [1][1] can't be converted to [100][100]

as you wrote it even if your input matrix data is 1x1 you have to store it in 100x100 array.
just declare double elem[100][100];
finally at run time ensure user input n < 100 to avoid a bug

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems.

First, the size of elem is unknown at compile time.  You should use elem[100][100] if you really want the variable on the stack and the size of the matrix really is 100x100.

Second, your determinant function creates a 10 thousand element matrix on the stack and it is recursive, which means you'll get a lot of them and likely run out stack space.  You should consider using a single temp matrix and reusing this for each recursive step.

Third, since you need the matrix size it to be dynamic, declare it on the heap.  Something like:

```
   double* elem = new double[n * n];
```

Strictly speaking you do not need to do this, but it will not waste as much memory as a 100x100 matrix if you are calculating the determinant of small matrices.

If you use a one dimensional array, you can pass in an array of any size to determinant (the determinant function should also take a one-dimensional array or double* instead of double[100][100]).  You will have to calculate the index yourself using matrix[order*j+i].