# Why does each element of my array automatically turn into the last element?

Tags: c

```
char *string[n];    
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    char string[60];
    fscanf(fptr, "%s%*[^\n]", string);
    strings[i] = string;
    printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
}
puts("Ended");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
```

This is part of my code in C ^. `strings[]` contains pointers to the first word of each line in the file. So if my file contains:

```
ABC 123
DEF 123
GHI 123
```

I get the following output:

```
ABC
DEF 
GHI
Ended
GHI
GHI
GHI
```

Which means there's nothing wrong with the initialisation. Then what is going on?

Comment: `strings[i] = string;` stores a pointer to an array that goes out of scope. Your `strings` array is full of *dangling pointers*

Comment: @UnholySheep How can I read a column from my file then?

Comment: You need to store pointers to memory that outlives the scope of the first `for` loop, e.g.: allocated using `malloc`

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wrote :

```
strings[i]=string
```

You were not copying the original string into the array because the “string” variable only contains a pointer (memory address) of the stack allocated string. When you go into the next iteration of the for loop, the stack allocated “string” variable gets freed/thrown away.

So your “strings” array contains pointers to unallocated memory. You should use “strcpy” instead. If the size of your “strings” array is not constant, use “malloc” then “strcpy”.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char strings[10][60];
    int n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char string[60];
        fscanf(fptr, "%s%*[^\n]", string);
        strcpy(strings[i], string);
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    puts("Ended");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Or, simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char strings[10][60];
    int n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fptr, "%s%*[^\n]", strings[i]);
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    puts("Ended");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you explain why "If the size of your “strings” array is not constant, use “malloc” then “strcpy"?

Comment: Yes sorry if I was unclear, I was talking about the size/length of each string. For instance, if you know you will have 10 strings and that each string is fewer than 60 characters, you can initialize the “strings” array in the following manner : “char strings[10][60]”

Comment: `char string[60];`
  `fscanf(fptr, "%s%*[^\n]",string);`
  `strcpy(strings{i], string);`

Comment: How does your “strings” array look?

Comment: You could also use fscanf on strings[i] instead of creating the “string” variable

Comment: The program doesnt execute succesfully. There's a segmentation fault at the strcpy line

Comment: it works for me, I'm posting my full source code of my working fix

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your issue in order to make show to other with the same issue that it is a viable solution. Thanks!

Comment: @HenryLeBerre consider if `n > 3` (for example `n=10`)

Comment: I'm looking into it

Comment: I works perfectly for me as long as the file has enough lines (where n <= lineCount)

Comment: Is your file long enough and is your array large enough (char strings[n][60])

Comment: If would be safer to check if `fscanf(fptr, "%s%*[^\n]", strings[i]);` returns `1` and break from the loop if not, adjusting the number of strings read.

Comment: You are right but I didn’t say anything since it is not the question but he should still add it

Comment: You have used a 2D array, what's the harm in using a 1D array the way I have done?

Comment: Your code would be slower since you would have use malloc, but you you have the flexibility of having each string be any length! Did my solution work out for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. Why do we have to malloc with single array and not with 2D array?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! The so called "1D" array is a list of pointers that point to the place in memory of the string they represent. You have to use malloc to allocate the area in memory where each string is stored. However, with the "2D" array, you specify the maximum size of each string so you don't have to dynamically allocate them.

Comment: So 2D array is stored in heap by default?

Comment: It is actually stored on the stack (in order to store on the stack, you have to know at compile-time how much memory you need)

Comment: I need to pass strings to another function and access all its strings, how can I do that?

Comment: Hi! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999951/passing-array-of-strings-to-functions-c should help you out!