# Variably-sized multi-dimensional array as argument to function?

Tags: c, function, data-structures

The issue I'm running into is defining the arguments of a function where the data structure is defined in a different file. In the main file I define the arrays `nPart[3]={a,b,c};`  and `particle p[np];` where `a,b,c,np` are integers. I then define the array:

```
particle *pp[ nPart[0] ][ nPart[1] ][ nPart[2] ][ np ];
```

which points to different particles in the `p` array.

In a second file I want to create a function:

```
void function(int np, particle *p, particle *pp[ nPart[0] ][ nPart[1] ][ nPart[2] ][ np ]){...}
```

however since I have defined `nPart` in the first file I'm unsure how I should do this. The second file's .h file is included in the first document.

I feel like I should somehow pass `nPart` as an argument to the function, along with some information about the location of `pp` and then be able to construct `pp` inside the function however I'm pretty lost as to how I should go about this.

EDIT: My lack of knowledge of terminology and C in general is probably making this more confusing that it should be.

I'll try to make a simple example:

In the first file's main function I define:

```
int x[3] = {1,2,2};
int *p[ x[0] ][ x[1] ][ x[2] ];
```

Then in the second file I want to be able to be able to use `*p` as an argument to functions. However, since `x` is defined locally in the main function I'm unsure how to do this.

The reason I'm trying to define `*p` in terms of `x` is that there are other things which also depend on `x` and so I want to be able to adjust just `x` rather than manually changing everything.

EDIT 2:
It seems that by switching the order of the arguments in my original code with `nPart` before `*pp` I am able to do what I wanted to do.

see relemos' answer here: 
[Passing multidimensional arrays as function arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c)

I guess I just wasn't searching with the right terminology the first time I looked for answers.

Comment: `pp` isn't a structure, it's a 4-dimensional array of pointers.

Comment: I think you are somewhat confused about function declarations/definitions. You don't need to know the actual definition of `npart` to write `function`. All you need is to define a parameter to `function` that has a same (or compatible) type to `npart`. So for example: `void function (int np, particle *p, particle *pp, int part_array[3]);`. And then when you call `function` you would pass in `npart` as the last argument.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. As you can tell I'm really a novice when it comes to C..

The issue I'm having is that ```pp``` is a multidimensional array with dimensions determined by the values of ```nPart``` but since ```nPart``` isn't defined in the second file, I don't know how to have ```pp``` as an argument.