# What is an mdspan, and what is it used for?

Tags: c++, c++-faq, std-span, mdspan

Over the past year or so I've noticed a few C++-related answers on StackOverflow refer to `mdspan`'s - but I've never actually seen these in C++ code. I tried looking for them in my C++ compiler's standard library directory and in [the C++ coding guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) - but couldn't find them. I *did* find `std::span`'s; I'm guessing they're related - but how? And what does this addition of "md" stand for?

Please explain what this mysterious entity is about, and when I might want to use it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `mdspan` is an extension of `std::span` for multiple dimensions - with a lot of (unavoidable) flexibile configurability w.r.t. memory layout and modes of access.

---

Before you read this answer, you should make sure you're clear on [what a `span` is and what it's used for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1593077). Now that that's out of the way: Since `mdspan`'s can be rather complex beasts (typically ~7x or more source code as an `std::span` implementation), we'll start with a simplified description, and keep the advanced capabilities for further below.

### "What is it?" (simple version)

An `mdspan<T>` is:

1. Literally, a "**m**ulti-**d**imensional span" (of type-`T` elements).
2. A generalization of `std::span<T>`, from a uni-dimensional/linear sequence of elements to multiple dimensions.
3. A non-owning view of a contiguous sequence of elements of type `T` in memory, interpreted as a multi-dimensional array.
4. Basically just a `struct { T * ptr; size_type extents[d]; }`  with some convenience methods  (for `d` dimensions determined at run-time).

#### Illustration of `mdspan`-interpreted layout

If we have:

```
std::vector v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
```

we can view the data of `v` as a 1D array of 12 elements, similar to  its original definition:

```
auto sp1 = std::span(v.data(), 12);
auto mdsp1 = std::mdspan(v.data(), 12);
```

or a 2D array of extents 2 x 6:

```
auto mdsp2 = std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 6 );
// (  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6 ),
// (  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12 )
```

or a 3D array 2 x 3 x 2:

```
auto ms3 = std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 3, 2);
// ( ( 1,  2 ), ( 3,  4 ), (  5,  6 ) ),
// ( ( 7,  8 ), ( 9, 10 ), ( 11, 12 ) )
```

and we could also consider it as a 3 x 2 x 2 or 2 x 2 x 3 array, or 3 x 4 and so on.

### "When should I use it?"

- (C++23 and later) When you want to use the multi-dimensional `operator[]` on some buffer you get from somewhere. Thus in the example above, `ms3[1, 2, 0]` is `11` and `ms3[0, 1, 1]` is `4` .
- When you want to pass multi-dimensional data without separating the raw data pointer and the dimensions. You've gotten a bunch of elements in memory, and want to refer to them using more than one dimension. Thus instead of:

  ```
  void print_matrix_element(
     float const* matrix, size_t row_width, size_t x, size_t y) 
  {
     std::print("{}", matrix[row_width * x + y]);
  }
  ```

  you could write:

  ```
  void print_matrix_element(
      std::mdspan<float const, std::dextents<size_t, 2>> matrix,
      size_t x, size_t y)
  {
     std::print("{}", matrix[x, y]);
  }
  ```
- As the right type for passing multidimensional C arrays around:
   C supports [multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array) perfectly... as long as their dimensions are given at compile time, and you don't try passing them to functions. Doing that is [a bit tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4051/1593077) because the outermost dimension experiences decay, so you would actually be passing a pointer. But with mdspans, you can write this:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename Extents>
  void print_3d_array(std::mdspan<T, Extents> ms3)
  {
     static_assert(ms3.rank() == 3, "Unsupported rank");
     // read back using 3D view
     for(size_t i=0; i != ms3.extent(0); i++) {
       fmt::print("slice @ i = {}\n", i);
       for(size_t j=0; j != ms3.extent(1); j++) {
         for(size_t k=0; k != ms3.extent(2); k++)
           fmt::print("{} ",  ms3[i, j, k]);
         fmt::print("\n");
       }
     }  
  }

  int main() {
      int arr[2][3][2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

      auto ms3 = std::mdspan(&arr[0][0][0], 2, 3, 2);
        // Note: This construction can probably be improved, it's kind of fugly

      print_3d_array(ms3);
  }
  ```

### Standardization status

While `std::span` was standardized in C++20, `std::mdspan` was not. However, it is part of C++23, which is almost-finalized (awaiting final ballot).

You can already use a [reference implementation](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan). It is part of the US' Sandia National Laboratory's ["Kokkos performance portability ecosystem"](https://kokkos.github.io/).

### "What are those 'extra capabilities' which `mdspan` offers?"

An `mdspan` actually has 4 template parameters, not just the element type and the extents:

```
template <
    class T,
    class Extents,
    class LayoutPolicy = layout_right,
    class AccessorPolicy = default_accessor<ElementType>
>
class mdspan;
```

This answer is already rather long, so we won't give the full details, but:

- Some of the extents can be "static" rather than "dynamic", specified in compile-time, and thus not stored in instance data members. Only the "dynamic" instances are stored. For example, this:

  ```
  auto my_extents extents<dynamic_extent, 3, dynamic_extent>{ 2, 4 };
  ```

  ... is an extents objects corresponding to `dextents<size_t>{ 2, 3, 4 }`, but which only stores the values `2` and `4` in the class instance; with the compiler knowing it needs to plug in `3` whenever the second dimension is used.
- You can have the dimensions go from-minor-to-major, in Fortran style instead of from-major-to-minor like in C. Thus, if you set `LayoutPolicy = layout_left`, then `mds[x,y]` is at `mds.data[mds.extent(0) * y + x]` instead of the usual `mds.data[mds.extent(1) * x + y]`.
- You can "reshape" your `mdspan` into another `mdspan` with different dimensions but the same overall size.
- You can define a layout policy with "strides": Have consecutive elements in the mdspan be at a fixed distance in memory; have extra offsets and the beginning and/or the end of each line or dimensional slice; etc.
- You can "cut up" your `mdspan` with offsets in every dimension (e.g. take a submatrix of a matrix) - and the result is still an `mdspan`! ... that's because you can have an `mdspan` with a `LayoutPolicy` which incorporates these offsets. This functionality is not available in C++23 IIANM.
- Using the `AccessorPolicy`, you can make `mdspan`'s which actually *do* own the data they refer to, individually or collectively.

### Further reading

- The official [`std::mdspan` proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0009r18.html), accepted into C++23.
- The [`std::mdspan` page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) on [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com/)
- [A gentle introduction to mdspan](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/wiki/A-Gentle-Introduction-to-mdspan), on the [Kokkos reference implementation](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan)'s wiki.
- [A look at `mdspan`](https://www.ashermancinelli.com/std-mdspan-tensors)'s, by Asher Macinelli.

<sub>(some examples were adapted from these sources.)</sub>