# How do I iterate an mdspan?

Tags: c++, iteration, c++23, ranged-loops, mdspan

So, I decided I want to use an [`mdspan`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75778573/1593077) rather than a combination of plain span + element access function. But - one obvious thing I want to do with my mdspan is iterate its elements. This is how I would do it with a 1D span:

```
std::vector vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
auto sp = std::span(vec.data(), 12);
for (auto x : sp) {
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

... but not for `mdspan`'s (using the [Kokkos implementation](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/tree/single-header)):

```
std::vector vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
auto ms = std::mdspan(vec.data(), 12);
for (auto x : ms) {
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Trying the above in GodBolt (with GCC trunk), I [get](https://godbolt.org/z/nxdYEjWez):

```
<source>:10:19: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
   10 |     for (auto x : ms) {
      |                   ^~
```

so, it seems mdspans are not ranges - even if they're one-dimensional (and I was even hoping to iterate 2D or 3D spans...). How come? And how *do* I iterate them?

Answer (score 4):

The iterator support for `mdspan` has been early on moved from the `mdspan` paper to deal with the specification to another paper (for which there does not seem to be any progress).

The `mdspan` proposal that has been voted into C++23 does neither contain iterators nor `submdspans` which would allow for creating slices of `mdspan` objects (on the latter [there is being actively worked on](https://wg21.link/P2630)).

There is a workaround to create a iterateable view on `mdspan` which can be used with algorithms from `std::ranges` using C++23 `views::cartesian_product`:

```
std::vector vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
auto ms = std::experimental::mdspan(vec.data(), 2, 6);

auto coeff_view =
    std::views::cartesian_product(std::views::iota(0uz, ms.extent(0)),
                                    std::views::iota(0uz, ms.extent(1))) |
    std::views::transform([ms](const auto index) {
        const auto [r, c] = index;
        return ms[r, c];
    });

std::cout << std::ranges::max(coeff_view) << '\n';
```

The bad news is that this workaround is way slower than operating on the underlying data directly as the index calculation seemingly cannot be optimized by the compiler as seen in this example: https://godbolt.org/z/7a4T6KxY6.

Another thing that can be useful is the layout information baked into the `mdspan` type.
When the `layout_type` of a `mdspan` is `layout_right` it is my understanding that it is safe to assume that the underlying data is contiguous and thus `data_handle()` can be safely transformed into a `std::span` which can be used with `std::ranges` algorithms:

```
template <typename Mdspan>
concept mdspan_specialization = std::same_as<
    Mdspan, std::experimental::mdspan<
                typename Mdspan::element_type, typename Mdspan::extents_type,
                typename Mdspan::layout_type, typename Mdspan::accessor_type>>;

template <mdspan_specialization Mdspan>
    requires(std::same_as<typename Mdspan::layout_type,
                          std::experimental::layout_right>)
auto to_span(const Mdspan ms) {
    return std::span{ms.data_handle(), ms.size()};
}
```

Comment: This basically means **don't use `mdspan`**. Where's the consistency? It was initiated as a *view*; Now just doesn't satisfy the requirements of a view.

Comment: @Red.Wave I wouldn't go that far to say *don't use `mdspan`*. It still serves as a vocabulary type, allowing to consume multidimensional data from different sources (imagine allowing to pass matrices from `eigen`, `opencv`, `ipp` all with a single `mdspan` interface).
With the template "metadata" there still seem to be ways to achieve good performance, just not out of the box. Maybe people will find better ways to deal with this as soon as first implementations make their way into the std libraries.

Comment: The risk of out of bounds indexing is best avoided using proper range algorithms and range-based `for`. If you need to define own wrappers, then redefining `mdspan` would be cheaper. Otherwise mere syntax sugar for indexing is not any appealing. Specifically if `mdarray` is supposed to be anything near this kind of `mdspan`, it is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to iterate an `mdspan` just like a plain C array:

```
std::vector vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
auto ms = std::experimental::mdspan(vec.data(), 12);
for (auto i : std::views::iota(0uz, ms.extent(0))) {
    std::cout << ms[i] << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

... and the same goes for multi-dimensional spans - just like multidimensional C arrays, but with the multi-argument `operator[]`:

```
std::vector vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
auto ms = std::experimental::mdspan(vec.data(), 2, 6);
for (auto r : std::views::iota(0uz, ms.extent(0))) {
    for (auto c : std::views::iota(0uz, ms.extent(1))) {
        std::cout << ms[r, c] << ' ';
        // ... and note that ms[r][c] won't work! :-(
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

See this second example at work: <kbd>[GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/35r81YG8a)</kbd>.

Now, I'm not sure *why* you can't just directly iterate - since `mdspan`'s could definitely have been made iterable. Perhaps the idea is to emphasize how the order in memory is not guaranteed? I wonder.